# What is the name of the "clip" for guitars

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I have came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oep9vIPrPQ).
The singer uses a kind of clip to make kind of tremolos, what is the name of it? You can see it repeatedly through the whole video. I am no musician, just guitar affitionate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ebow. It is called ebow. I must write 30 characters.

Comment: would you recommend some of the ebows that amazon sells?
This is the first that appears http://www.amazon.com/Heet-Sound-PLUSEBOW-E-bow-Guitar/dp/B000N5MK8M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1428086544&sr=8-1&keywords=ebow

Comment: I have the same but I don't think there are other models. If you think you will get it to good use then go for it.